# swing component not fully functioning into javafx application

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jcomponent

I have two separate based on Swing and Javafx. Now i need to open Swing application inside Javafx Tab pane by below code

```
 SyntaxTester ob = new SyntaxTester(filepath);
        SwingNode swingnode = new SwingNode();
        JComponent jcomp = new JComponent() {
        };
        jcomp.add(ob.getContentPane());
        swingnode.setContent(jcomp);
        BorderPane borderpane = new BorderPane(swingnode);
        tab.setContent(borderpane);
```

Basically this Swing application is JEditorPane based editor. Swing application is added and working successfully inside Tab pane but the issue is that, there is hinting feature and after selecting text from hint, editor looses it's cursor and user again manually click on the editor. Although Swing application separately working fine. Please help me with resolve it. Thanks in advance.
This is what happening when user select from hint list.

```
if (jLstItems.getSelectedIndex() >= 0) {
            result = jLstItems.getSelectedValue().toString();
        } else {
            result = jTxtItem.getText();
        }
        char pressed = evt.getKeyChar();
        if (pressed != '\n') {
            result += (pressed == '\t') ? ' ' : pressed;
        }
       setVisible(false);
        target.replaceSelection(result);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can understand and reproduce your problem. If you do it, you'll have better chances to get your question answered.